# MYSQL service error & cannot start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My MySQL service & databases seem to be offline on my own VPS. It has had no problem over the past months, so I am unsure as to what caused this. The last thing I did was disable strict mode on `mariadb` for a `mybb` plugin to work.

This was an hour ago, and now the database seems to be offline.

I ran `systemctl status mariadb.service`, here is the output:

```
# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.12 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset:
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Tue 2018-01-30 21:57
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 6979 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_STAR
  Process: 6970 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUC
  Process: 12929 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_W
  Process: 12774 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VA
  Process: 12770 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_STAR
  Process: 12767 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/r
 Main PID: 12929 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Jan 30 21:57:24 control systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'
lines 1-16/16 (END)...skipping...
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.12 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Tue 2018-01-30 21:57:24 EST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 6979 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6970 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12929 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=KILL)
  Process: 12774 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-envir
  Process: 12770 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12767 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 12929 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Jan 30 21:57:24 control systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

My `phpmyadmin` error is:

```
#2002 - Connection refused &mdash; The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I am unsure what the next step would be in debugging this issue on my debian server.

Comment: Check out this CentOS fix to this problem: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52649.... These may help too: https://serverfault.com/questions/812719/mysql-mariadb-not-starting

Comment: you should ask this on [dba.se] Or, flag to get it migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Because its a SIGKILL its likely that the service timed out, see extending `TimeoutStartSec` [mariadb systemd documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/)